# How can I require a generated file in my SConscript?

Tags: scons

I'm working on adding googletest unit testing to a large project.

We have a top level SConstruct, which calls SConscripts for each of the git submodules, which may further call other SConstructs contained in each component.

One of these SConscripts will build the googletest framework, which will create the 'gtest.h' file among others. I need to include 'gtest.h' in my source file (test1.cpp) which is in a different repo that has it's own SConscript.

How can I require the gtest.h in test SConscript file before test1.cpp consumes it?

Imagine something like:

Top level SConstruct:

```
env.SConscript('{path to Gtest}/SConscript')
env.SConscript('{path to my unit test}/SConscript')
```

SConscript for building Gtest:

```
env2 = env.Clone()
def buildGtest(target, source, env):
  #Assuming I have a CMake file that does this in the directory...
  subprocess.run(['cmake', '../'], cwd='build/')
  subprocess.run(['make'], cwd='build/')
  
env2.Command(['gtest.h', 'build/libgtest.a', 'build/libgtest_main.a'], [], buildGtest)
```

SConscript for my unit test:

```
env2 = env.Clone()
env2.Require('{path to gtest}/build/include/gtest.h') # This doesn't seem to work
env2.Append(CPPPATH='{path to gtest}/build/include')
env2.Object(target = 'test1.o', source = 'test1.cpp')
```

Comment: If the build command for googletest produces the gtest.h, then adding gtest.h for later commands should worker. Or i don't get something

Comment: It looks like it's trying to compile test1.cpp before the gtest.h is put in place. I keep getting a compilation error that it can't find gtest.h, even though I've added the path to where gtest.h is generated to the SConscript for test1.cpp

Comment: Oh, ok I see, gtest.h should be passed directly to Object directive. (at least according to my limited scons knowledge) it should be done in the way it is returned from the Command directive. You should be able to print it to see. It most likely have to be exactly same string

Comment: It looks like SCons won't take a .h in an Object directive. I tried, but then it complained that it doesn't know how to build a source file with a suffix of '.h', and then gave me a list of acceptable suffixes (.c, .cpp, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your CPPPATH includes the location where googletest generates the header file.

This is not great. You should specify at least one source file.  I'm guessing you have a CmakeList.txt and a bunch of source files you should list here, so it will rebuild if they change.

```
env2.Command(['gtest.h', 'build/libgtest.a', 'build/libgtest_main.a'], [], buildGtest)
```

Additionally I'd change your buildGtest to the following.

buildGtest = ["cd build; cmake ../','cd build; make']

And get rid of your function.

```
env2.Command(['gtest.h', 'build/libgtest.a', 'build/libgtest_main.a'], [], buildGtest)
```

Then SCons will scan your source file and know that it requires that file.

You can check the dependency tree that SCons is aware of by running as

`scons --tree=prune`

It may be quite verbose, but you'll see all the dependencies.

You should also be able to run as

`scons --tree=prune {path to my unit test}/test.o`

Comment: "Modern" C++ has led to the use of certain these header-only libraries, so we have to deal with it :)  I've had to wrangle googletest before.